# Why in Xcode 6, I am getting "You are not registered as an Apple developer" while trying to upload a binary?

Tags: xcode6

I have an active iOS developer account, and an active provisioning profile. I uploaded a binary just two weeks ago with Xcode 5 without any problem. Now, I am trying to upload another binary with Xcode 6, and after archiving, I go to organizer/archives as usual and click submit or validate or export. In any case I receive this message: "You are not registered as an Apple developer". Does anybody have the same issue, or have any idea what the problem is?

**Edit**

I uploaded the binary with Xcode 5. I guess I should report this as Xcode 6 bug!

Comment: I have the same problem! Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following fixed it for me:

In Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, I had an Apple ID account that wasn't a registered development, in addition to my own valid account. I deleted the unregistered Apple ID, and it now works.

Comment: No problem :) It's definitely an xcode bug. You should go ahead and report it!

Comment: Yea, I reported the bug. Let's hope they fix it soon.

Comment: What is the bug report number?

Answer (score 3):

I had *almost* the same situation as @iht, except that the "unregistered" Apple ID was a legit-but-new developer ID.

Turns out I hadn't "signed" the dev agreement yet, so I logged into developer.apple.com, was presented with the wall of fine print, clicked Agree and was set to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just sign in on `developer.apple.com` and accept the agreement.